# trying to run an .exe file in lua

Tags: lua, command, exe

recently i have been trying to run a script in lua that through `os.execute()` will execute a script in C# compiled into an executablethat is in the **same directory** as my script.
In my first attempt adding the entire directory until the executable worked:

```lua
os.execute("C:\\ServerTest\\test\\tex\\testcode.exe")
```

however I need this script to work on other computers, which means I can't add the entirely path to the file.I tried countless methods to execute the .exe file inside the same directory without using the entire path and none of the methods worked

```lua
os.execute("./testcode")
os.execute [[".\testcode.exe"]]
os.execute(".\\testcode.exe")
os.execute "testcode.exe"
```

I even tried to create an environment variable and run the entire directory from it xD

```lua
os.execute("set wTest=%cd%")
os.execute("%wTest%\\testcode.exe")
```

but nothing worked. I also tried to use `io.popen()` but didn't get results either (because the executable will close a computer process, it does not give any output :V)

does anyone know how I can do this?????

Comment: `local exe = arg[0]:gsub("[^/\\]+$", "testcode.exe"); os.execute('"'..exe..'"')`

Comment: This is not a cmd question, this question in **no way** is related to the windows cmd.exe console. Please read tags before assigning them.

Comment: @NekoMusume - A command for `os.execute()` must be a correct `cmd.exe` command line as this command is directly passed to Windows by ISO C function `system`.

Comment: Thank you @EgorSkriptunoff, your code really worked!!! <3  but I have a question, after your comment, I have been searching about the `gsub` function and I'm still a little confused as to what your code does xD I tried to study patterns but I still don't understand it very well. What args[0] collects? and what `[^/\\]+$` do? anyway, already thank you for your help :D

Comment: `arg[0]` is the path to your script. `gsub` replaces the script name with exe name.  Good tutorial about patterns is [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)